# Why does RowUpdated not fire when RowUpdating does?

Tags: gridview

I use this code to invoke a GridView:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="detailView" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
OnRowEditing="EditRow" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit" OnRowUpdating="UpdateRow" OnRowUpdated="RowUpdated" />
```

UpdateRow runs fine but RowUpdated never fires.

Comment: I think what is not happening has to do with the fact that I am using DataTable objects for my data source. All examples I've encountered presume a SqlDataConnection with builtin Update, etc, commands. Presumably, upon completion of one of those commands, something happens to tell the system that Updated has happened. In that case, RowUpdated would be fired. It seems that I simply cannot use RowUpdated for my "manual" updating process.

Comment: I love the question number! (867-5309)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have an application that runs as intended. It makes use of the OnItemUpdating routine configured in the DetailsView control. But I have also proved that the OnItemUpdated routine never fires, even with the success of the Updating routine.

My conclusion is that this combination of handlers is somehow controlled by the nature of the data source. In my case, I am using only DataTable objects for sources.